# Selecting data between 2 ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I've got some problem with implement loop for selecting data between 2 ranges.
I've got 2 values: 2020-04-01 in `Range("E2")` and 2020-06-01 in `Range("E4")`. After this I am looking for these 2 dates in `column A` and there comes some difficulties. It is possible to select both of ranges with this:

```
Sub FindDate()

    Dim date1 As String, date2 As String
    Dim date1Cell As Range, date2Cell As Range, valRng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set valRng = Range("A1:A1000")
    date1 = Format(Range("E2"), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    date2 = Format(Range("E4"), "yyyy-mm-dd")

    Set date1Cell = Cells.Find(What:=CDate(date1), After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
            , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        'date1Cell.Select
    Set date2Cell = Cells.Find(What:=CDate(date2), After:=Cells(date1Cell), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
            , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        'date2Cell.Select
    For i = date1Cell To date2Cell
    ------------------------    ------------------------    ------------------------
        'How do I set up that loop to search and select from date1Cell to date2Cell
    ------------------------    ------------------------    ------------------------
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `For i = date1Cell.Row To date2Cell.Row` and take care to assort the analyzed range to the incremented row number.

Answer (score 1):

A short example using a loop rather than `Find`:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim date1 As String, date2 As String, cell As Range
    Dim date1Cell As Range, date2Cell As Range, valRng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set valRng = Range("A1:A1000")
    date1 = Format(Range("E2"), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    date2 = Format(Range("E4"), "yyyy-mm-dd")

    For Each a In valRng
        If a.Text = date1 Then Set date1Cell = a
        If a.Text = date2 Then Set date2Cell = a
    Next a

    Range(date1Cell, date2Cell).Select
End Sub
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

You do not require a loop to do the actual selection.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any looping at all, just use a match:

```
Sub FindDate()

Dim date1 As String: date1 = Format(Range("E2"), "yyyy-mm-dd")
Dim date2 As String: date2 = Format(Range("E4"), "yyyy-mm-dd")
Dim dtRng As Range: Set dtRng = Range("A1:A10000")

Range("A" & Application.Match(date1, dtRng, 0) & ":A" & Application.Match(date2, dtRng, 0)).Select

End Sub
```